# PyQt: How do you clear focus on startup?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, focus, pyqt5, startup

When I start up my PyQt GUI, the focus immediately goes to the text box.

I want there to be no focus on any of the buttons at the start of the program, especially not the text box.

Is there a way to remove the focus entirely or at least move the focus to a button or something?

Thanks

Comment: `mytextbox.clearFocus()` or `someotherwidget.setFocus()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks, clearFocus() didn't work, but setFocus() did.

Answer (score 1):

`clearFocus()` seems to work after a certain amount of delay after the window is visible. I also used `setFocus()` on the `QMainWindow` and then the textedit field lost focus.

Answer (score 1):

Create a button with dimensions 0 wide by 0 high.

Set it as the default button and also early in the tab order before the other controlls that except focus; but note that it will be triggered if the user presses ENTER in some edit controls.

Call *self.ui.yourbutton*.setFocus() if desired for example after restore from minimized

Comment: In PYQT5, I have a QMessagebox that seemingly *requires* a control to have focus. MyControl.clearFocus() didn't solve the issue, so I created a label widget with an empty string, placed focus on that, and then drew an `OK` button on top of the empty label widget. Now it appears like nothing has focus, and hitting `Enter` closes the message box.